# How to change auto open page by Livereload in Yeoman?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, livereload

When I use yeoman and run `grunt server`, livereload will open a webpage 127.0.0.1:9000 automatically.
But I use nginx proxy 127.0.0.1:9000 to foo.com, so I want auto open foo.com instead of 127.0.0.1:9000.

I checked `Gruntfile.js` and found the configuration, but seemed no way to change the hostname:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
```

I can't change the port & hostname in options because the server still should be run in 9000, and if I do that, `Fatal error: listen EACCES` will be shown. I just want change the auto open page.

And is there any further docs to customize livereload in grunt?

I just generate these files by yeoman.

Gruntfile.js:

```
// Generated on 2013-11-15 using generator-angular 0.6.0-rc.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
      coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:dist']
      },
      coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:test']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: ['last 1 version'],
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          // open: true,
          open: {
            server: {
              url: 'http://foo.com'
            }
          },
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },
    coffee: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceRoot: ''
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false
      },
      dist: {},
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
      dist: {}
    },*/
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    },
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      // By default, your `index.html` <!-- Usemin Block --> will take care of
      // minification. This option is pre-configured if you do not wish to use
      // Usemin blocks.
      // dist: {
      //   files: {
      //     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
      //       '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      //       '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
      //     ]
      //   }
      // }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
          //collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          useShortDoctype: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true*/
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: [
            'generated/*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'coffee:dist',
        'compass:server',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'coffee',
        'compass',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'coffee',
        'compass:dist',
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin',
        'htmlmin'
      ]
    },
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma": "~0.10.4",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

Comment: any success with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current seemingly correct config for current version of grunt-contrib-connect (0.7.1) is to set the `options.open` variable to

```
connect: {
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: {
        target: 'http://foo.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [grunt-contrib-connect docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#open).

But when doing this I ran into the issue that code changes get picked up but no longer trigger a browser refresh. See my recent question: [grunt watch no longer refreshes Chrome when using custom open connect config via https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947636/grunt-watch-no-longer-refreshes-chrome-when-using-custom-open-connect-config)

Comment: U r right, seems new version solved this problem. I have finished that project, still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the fallowing worked for me:

```
 open: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>',
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit options of `open:server` target:

By default you get:

```
open: {
  server: {
    url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
  }
},
```

Comment: When I update `open: true` to this, the page still won't auto open.

Comment: Hm? just change `url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'` to `url: 'http://foo.com'` ...

Comment: Yes, I changed it, but no page popup.

Comment: Please provide your Gruntfile.

Comment: I add file details, I just generated them by yeoman, and didn't do much change. May be the open.server function not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing `port` in

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
```

I used port 8999 instead of 9000 and it simply worked.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I was receiving the very same error as you when running `grunt server`.  I'm on Windows 7.